# How to concatenate expr into the pgfplotstabletypeset?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I have a file with time in seconds and I want to make a expression inside the pgfplotstabletypeset to convert the seconds into 2h35m40s. I only get how to convert to hours, minutes and seconds but with out concatenate them. How do I do that?

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
     columns={Tamanho,UiSCSI},
     columns/Tamanho/.style={
            column name={\textbf{Tamanho}},
            precision=4,
            column type=l,
            preproc/expr={##1/1000},
            postproc cell content/.append code={
               \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={}{ GB}}%
            },
        },
 columns/UiSCSI/.style={
            column name={\textbf{UiSCSI}},
            fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,
            preproc/expr={{##1/3600}},
            postproc cell content/.append code={
               \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={}{h}}%
            },
            column type=r,
        },
    ]{metricas/data.dat}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a custom preproc

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
a b
some 52894
stuff 3600
dummy 7201
}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[1000 sep=,
columns/a/.style={string type},
columns/b/.style={string type,
    preproc cell content/.code={%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\myvar%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
        \pgfmathparse{floor(\myvar/3600)}%
        \pgfmathfloattoint{\pgfmathresult}%
        \edef\hhh{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathparse{floor((\myvar-\hhh*3600)/60)}%
        \pgfmathfloattoint{\pgfmathresult}%
        \edef\mmm{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathparse{\myvar-\hhh*3600 - \mmm*60}%
        \pgfmathfloattoint{\pgfmathresult}%
        \edef\sss{\pgfmathresult}%
        \edef\temp{%
            \noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\hhh h\mmm m\sss s}}%
        \temp%
        \pgfkeys{pgf/fpu=false}%
    },
}
]\mytable

\end{document}
```

Not the most efficient computation but shows the essential method.

[image]